# Create UserControl WPF buttons for ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I need help with buttons in list view. I am creating custom form for SCSM. List view is working without problems, but I need add there Add button, Open button and Delete button. Add button working without problem, but other buttons do nothing. Can anybody help me with it?

Thanks

XAML code is here:

```
<ListView Name="ListViewMonitor" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,00,0" MinHeight="100" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomRelatedMonitor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=Strings[ID].Value, FallbackValue=ID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:FormView}}}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding Path=Strings[CustomAssetStatus].Value, FallbackValue=CustomAssetStatus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:FormView}}}" Width="Auto">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                <smcontrols:ListPicker Name="listPickerAssetStatus" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" ParentCategoryId="{Binding Source=12435943-EBA1-3E78-BB6C-A731E44EDCFD, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CustomAssetStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>

                                </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Button  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="buttonAddMonitor"  Height="20" Width="65" Content="{Binding Path=Strings[buttonAdd].value, FallbackValue=Add, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:FormView}}}" Click="buttonAddMonitor_Click" />
                            <Button  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="buttonRemoveMonitor"  Height="20" Width="65" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ListViewMonitor, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" Content="{Binding Path=Strings[buttonRemove].value, FallbackValue=Remove, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:FormView}}}" Click="buttonRemoveMonitor_Click" />
                            <Button  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="buttonOpenMonitor"  Height="20" Width="65" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ListViewMonitor, Path=SelectedItems.Count}" Content="{Binding Path=Strings[buttonOpen].value, FallbackValue=Open, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:FormView}}}" Click="buttonOpenMonitor_Click" />
                        </StackPanel>
```

Code for buttons:

```
public ListView ListViewAllMonitors { get; set; }
    private ListView GetListView (string Name)
    {
        switch (Name)
        {
            case "buttonAddMonitor":
            case "buttonRemoveMonitor":
            case "buttonOpenMonitor":
                {
                    return this.ListViewAllMonitors;
                }
            default:
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("ListView for control: {0}- not found", Name));
                }
        }
    }



    private void buttonAddMonitor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonAdd_Click(new Guid("DD3BDB96-BC9E-D46E-5847-BAB387039B36"), ListViewMonitor);
    }

    private void ButtonAdd_Click(Guid mpClassGuid, ItemsControl listView)
    {
        FormUtilities.Instance.LaunchAddInstancePickerDialog(listView.ItemsSource as Collection<IDataItem>, mpClassGuid);
    }



    private void buttonRemoveMonitor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        var CustomListView = GetListView(button.Name);
        if (CustomListView == null) return;
        var list = (IList<IDataItem>)CustomListView.ItemsSource;
        if (list == null) return;
        foreach (IDataItem item in new ArrayList(CustomListView.SelectedItems))
        {
            list.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    private void buttonOpenMonitor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        var ListView = GetListView(button.Name);
        if (ListView == null) return;
        OpenInstance(ListView);
    }

    public void OpenInstance(ListView ListView)
    {
        if (ListView == null) return;
        foreach (IDataItem dataItem in ListView.SelectedItems)
        {
            FormUtilities.Instance.PopoutForm(dataItem);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You may want to look into the MVVM pattern for your WPF applications, it will make working with WPF so much easier.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am beginner. I am trying to learn WPF, but sometimes it is littlebit complicated. I need only to check if the buttonRemoveMonitor is correct or if I making somewhere a mistake.

Comment: Why don't you debug it. Put a break point into your function's first line by pressing F9 and then press F5 to start your application. When you press the button, it should jump into your code and you can step through it line by line and check all variables.